# Why does the filter function affect another array? I do not understand how it turns out, if it is a different array

Tags: vuejs2

In what magical way is the array of this.listshop also filtered? I do not understand it, kill me. In my understanding this.listshop should not change in this case! But it is filtered too!

Short Code;

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="" v-model="search">

     data () {
                    return {
                      listshop: [],
                      arr_sort: [],
                      search: ''
    }
                },

    methods: {
      getGames() {
          axios.get('/get-jsonshop')
            .then(response => {
              this.listshop = response.data;

         this.arr_sort = this.listshop

          });

    watch: {
            search: function() {


              if (this.search.length > 0) {
              for (var i = 0; i < this.arr_sort.length; i++) {
              this.arr_sort[i].shops = (this.arr_sort[i].shops.filter(ar => ar.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1))

     }

    }
console.log(this.listshop) // --  ???????????????   
}
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing `this.listshop` as a reference to `this.arr_sort` in your `getGames` method. Look up and use [Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) or `cloneDeep` from underscore. Every time you modify `arr_sort`, `listshop`changes also.

```
this.arr_sort = _.cloneDeep(this.listshop)
```

or

```
  this.arr_sort = this.listshop.slice()
```